# TestCafe issue, onChange event not triggred for input box in a modal dialog box

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am trying to update a number on the screen. I click on the update menu that lets me update a number. When I click on the update button it will open a modal dialog box with an empty text box for the new number and a save button. The save button is initially disabled. If the user manually types in a number in the text box, the onChange event will trigger and the save button is enabled. However, if I let the testcafe script to put a number in the number text box, the save button remains disabled. My guess is that when I use the testcafe `.typeText(inputbox,'123')` it does not fire the onChange event on the text box. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

---

[image: [1]]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to put "alert" or "print" to see if onChange method is triggered?
Furthermore, can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

TestCafe have fixed [the problem](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1558) with the `onChange` event for `react-dom` since the 15.6.0 version. Please try to use TestCafe 0.16.2.
If the problem persists, please provide your page's URL.

Comment: Will give it a try and let you know